# How to prevent a Lua callback, in the C API's registry, from being garbage collected?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I'm using a Lua 5.3 callback system in my C program. The Lua script is only ran once, to register callbacks. I'd like to prevent the callbacks from being GC'd, without disabling the GC altogether.

Callback code:

```cpp
LuaEventHandler* presentEvent = FindLuaEvent("present");
if (presentEvent != NULL) {
    lua_rawgeti(lState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, presentEvent->luaFuncRef);
    lua_pushvalue(lState, 1);
    lua_pcall(lState, 0, 0, 0);
    //presentEvent->luaFuncRef = luaL_ref(lState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
}
```

Callback adding code:

```cpp
LUACFUNCTION(RegisterCallbackLua) {
    int ref = luaL_ref(lState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    const char* name = luaL_checkstring(lState, 1);
    RegisterLuaEvent(ref, name);
    return 0;
}

LuaEventHandler* RegisterLuaEvent(int pLuaFuncRef, const char* pEventName) {
    LuaEventHandler* eventHandler = new LuaEventHandler();
    eventHandler->luaFuncRef = pLuaFuncRef;
    eventHandler->eventName = pEventName;
    printf("Callback registered: %s\n", pEventName);
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (luaEventHandlerList[i] != 0)
            continue;
        luaEventHandlerList[i] = eventHandler;
        break;
    }
    return eventHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was bad memory management.

luaEventHandlerList should've been a vec, I directly referencing a lua string, etc etc